# Does Visual Studio Community Edition include the HTML5 video api?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013

I have been trying to teach myself HTML5 and cannot get the simplest of javascript commands to run. I am using the VS 2013 community edition and trying to run videos in chrome. The videos will play fine in the native tool but if I try to run simple commands like

```
var vid = document.getElementById('vid');

function play() {
vid.play();
}


<video id="vid">
<source src="zaza.mp4" />
</video>
```

The screen flashes and nothing happens. I'm starting to think VS community doesn't have support for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Community has no problems with JS. Does your video element actually *have* an id "vid"?

Comment: Yes sir. <video id="vid">

Comment: *Darn! do not hit Enter. Do not hit Enter*

Sorry. So as I was saying:
"The screen flashes and nothing happens. "
Yes, something *does* happen: the screen flashes! ==> Event seems to be fired. :-)
Debug when you try via JS: Do you run it from within VS or try to start from IIS? Is your path to the video still valid *then*?

Comment: And does that element exist _before_ your script is executed? (Meaning, is the script placed _after_ it, or is your script executed only on an event such a load or DOMready?)

Comment: My javascript is at the bottom, so I believe the controls are available. When I say nothing happens I mean, I can see the video loaded in the controller. When I click the simple input button <button id="play" type="button" onclick="play()">Play</button> the screen recycles but the video never plays. Its as if I were using an asp button instead of doing a client call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with how I coded the button itself. I dragged another HTML button from the toolbox in and used that and it worked. I have no idea why since I compared the markup and it was the same.